# Elisp Debugger Not Popping Up

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I toggle global debug mode for the first time in an emacs session and attempt to execute a piece of invalid lisp the backtrace window pops up. However if I close this window and delete the backtrace buffer and then try and execute another piece of invalid elisp the backtrace buffer no longer gets created and no window pops up. I have looked through the manual to try and figure out why this is happening to no avail, any help would be much apprecaited.

Comment: Perhaps you are still in `recursive-edit`, which is usually seen in the mode-line by `[` and `]`.  You need to exit out of `recursive-edit` before the `*backtrace*` buffer will reappear.  Evaluating `(top-level)` will work and there are other methods to exit the debugger properly.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem. I will have to read up on recursive edit. This happens when I kill the buffer instead of pressing q so I assume the function that key is locally bound to exits the recursive edit.

Comment: To see the keys in the `debugger-mode-map`, you can type `M-x describe-mode RET` while point is in the `*Backtrace*` buffer.  Or, you can see it anytime by typing `M-x describe-variable RET debugger-mode-map RET`.  In this particular instance, `q` is bound to `top-level`.  The function `exit-recursive-edit` just backs out of one level -- there could be many levels that are active.  The function `abort-recursive-edit` will exit out of all levels.  The function `top-level` has a doc-string that states:  "*Exit all recursive editing levels.  This also exits all active minibuffers.*"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that killing the `*Backtrace*` buffer doesn't actually make you leave the debugger (contrary to hitting `c` or `q`), so you're still in the recursive edit where further debugging is disabled (so as to avoid jumping further into the debugger ad-nauseam).

I recommend you use `C-]` to get out of this situation.  But I also recommend that you file this with `M-x report-emacs-bug` since it would make sense to exit the debugger when the backtrace buffer gets killed.

Comment: +1. Also: (1) If the current recursive edit is a backtrace buffer you can use `C-x 4 b *Backtrace*` to visit it. (2) `M-x top-level` will take you to the top level, exiting from *all* levels of recursive edits.